# Can't set value of variable without it returning nil

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, null

I've run into a strange issue with Swift - All I am trying to do is update a label from my model.  This is a method in `viewController.swift` that is called from `model.swift`:

```
func scoreDisplay(score:Double) {
    print(score)
    scoreLabel.text = score
    CounterView().counter = Int(score)
}
```

The `print(score)` line prints the score properly, but then on the next line I get the error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`.  My `scoreLabel.text` isn't `nil`, and `score` is not `nil`, so I'm not sure where this error could be coming from.

I set the value of `scoreLabel.text` before running this function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    scoreLabel.text = "20"
    // Here, I call a function from another class, and within that function scoreDisplay() is called
}
```

Even if I set it up like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    scoreLabel.text = "20"
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // Here I call a function from another class that calls scoreDisplay()
}
```

It still says `scoreLabel.text` is `nil`.  How is that possible if I give it a value in `viewDidLoad` and then I call `scoreDisplay()` in `viewDidAppear`? If I use `scoreDisplay()` directly from `viewDidAppear` it works fine, but I need to call `scoreDisplay()` within another function in another class, and that seems to be the issue.

Comment: That probably means that scoreLabel is nil ...

Comment: Why make the parameter optional if you use it as mandatory without checking?

Comment: When you call `scoreDisplay` from the other class, how do you get your reference to `viewController`?  Also, what do you see if you print `scoreLabel` inside the `scoreDisplay` function?

Comment: Printing `scoreLabel.text` returns `nil`, so that's definitely where the issue is cropping up.

Comment: I call `scoreDisplay()` like this from my model: `ViewController().scoreDisplay(score)`

Comment: There's your problem.  `ViewController().scoreDisplay(score)` creates a **new** view controller object and, since you don't load its view, the outlet never gets filled in.  You need a way for your caller to get a reference to the view controller that is already handling the active views.

Comment: How do I reference the ViewController without creating a new object?

Comment: That depends entirely on how your app is structured.  The most flexible is probably having your model object post a notification with the information the controller needs.  The controller listens for the notification and updates itself.

Answer (score 2):

Since your function takes an optional value you've already got a good starting point to use optional binding to ensure `score` won't cause you any trouble in places where a `Double` is required.

You should also check if the `counter` property on `CounterView` is unwrapping the `Int` you are trying to instantiate. This may be another source of errors.

See the [Swift Programming Language — Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333) for details.

In general you should avoid using *Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals* (continue reading [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333)) unless you have no other choice.